# MySQL insert/update based on two columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to update or insert data based on two columns.

Every user can have entries. Every user's entry has to be unique to the user. Different users can share entry IDs.

Every entry will contain a piece of text.

```
id, user_id, entry_number, data
1, 1, 1, "hello"
2, 1, 2, "world"
3, 1, 3, "fizz"
4, 2, 1, "buzz"
5, 2, 3, "fizzbuzz"
```

I want to be able to insert/update (depending on if it exists) this data. How do I do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could check if the entry exists with the data you want to insert, if it exists you update else insert.. Some code would be nice too..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index on the pair (user_id, entry_number) and then use the

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

However, this ON DUPLICATE KEY might be a nonstandard extension of MySQL (please check?). If you intend to use it on different database engine, you may need to make the check manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use REPLACE: "REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted." in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

```
REPLACE tbl_name (id, user_id, entry_number, data) VALUES (1, 1, 1, "something")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying the id?

Comment: If you don't specify the id it doesn't match an existing value so it will have it's normal behavior and act just as an INSERT and never as an UPDATE. If you really don't want to use the id you'll have to check the existence of a match before this in order to decide if it's an INSERT or an UPDATE that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

```
REPLACE INTO your_table (id, user_id, entry_number, data)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, "hello2")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying the id?